# create map from dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json string as below in a dataframe

```
  aaa  |  bbb |  ccc |ddd | eee          
 --------------------------------------
   100 | xxxx |  123 |yyy|2017
   100 | yyyy |  345 |zzz|2017
   200 | rrrr |  500 |qqq|2017
   300 | uuuu |  200 |ttt|2017
   200 | iiii |  500 |ooo|2017
```

I want to get the result as

```
 {100,[{xxxx:{123,yyy}},{yyyy:{345,zzz}}],2017}
 {200,[{rrrr:{500,qqq}},{iiii:{500,ooo}}],2017}
 {300,[{uuuu:{200,ttt}}],2017}
```

Kindly help

Comment: Your title and question don't match at all.

Comment: what should i mention

Comment: The output that you're suggesting isn't a json.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
 val df = data
    .withColumn("cd", array('ccc, 'ddd)) // create arrays of c and d
    .withColumn("valuesMap", map('bbb, 'cd)) // create mapping
    .withColumn("values", collect_list('valuesMap) // collect mappings
                 .over(Window.partitionBy('aaa)))
    .withColumn("eee", first('eee) // e is constant, just get first value of Window
                 .over(Window.partitionBy('aaa)))
   .select("aaa", "values", "eee") // select only columns that are in the question selected
   .select(to_json(struct("aaa", "values", "eee")).as("value")) // create JSON
```

Make sure you do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._`
```

Comment: Thanks Gaweda. But partitionby is not working. But now the requirement is changes. I have list as below

Comment: @gayathri What do you mean by "not working"? I've tested it on your data. If you want to have plain String list, you can do collect()

Comment: Hi Gaweda, iam using IntelliJ(scala 2.10.6)  .withColumn("valuesMap", map('bbb, 'cd)) , map is not recognized and aso over(Window.partitionBy('aaa)) not recognized. I have imported the sql.functions Pls help

Comment: map is inside functions object, so it should be visible

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map defining the values as constants with `lit()` or taking them from other columns in the dataframe with `$"col_name"`, like this:

```
val new_df = df.withColumn("map_feature", map(lit("key1"), lit("value1"), lit("key2"), $"col2"))
```